# How to align list Items with font-awesome icon next line text?

Tags: html, css

[image: Align font-awesome icon list item with span]

A picture paints a thousand words. The text on the next line needs to align on same margin as above.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
<p><em class="fa fa-square"></em><span>Name and surnafdddddddddddddds sdgfh dh hdfh df hdsh dfh dsfh sdfhdsfh sdf hsdfhdsfhme</span></p>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    display: table;
    a{
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    span{
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

After @panther update:

[image: Aligning list items with font-awesome line breaks]

It is acceptable, however the fontawesome icon is now off centre.

Comment: Just add `margin-top:2px;` to `em` on panther's answer

Comment: a bit late for the party but I thought someone had to mention font awesome's built-in feature http://stackoverflow.com/a/35357616/759452

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try to use [font awesome's built-in solution for lists](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#list):

> Use `fa-ul` and `fa-li` to easily replace default bullets in unordered lists.

[image: font awesome's built-in solution for lists]

---

In your case, the code will change to something like this:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa fa-square"></i><span>Name and surnafdddddddddddddds sdgfh dh hdfh df hdsh dfh dsfh sdfhdsfh sdf hsdfhdsfhme</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It looks like you left off the fa-li in the list item. But I appreciate your answer. Was going around in circles before finding this. (I still had to make some adjustments on the .fa-li css, but this answer got me on the right path!)

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for st. like this.

```
em {float: left;}
a, span {margin: 0 0 0 20px; display: block;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not do these:

1. Apply `position` with a `property value` of `relative` to `li` to avoid overlap
2. Insert the square with `:before` selector and add `position` with a `property value` of `Absolute` o its block of `CSS`.

That way you can position it as needed. You have `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` properties to work with as you position it.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>
<p>Some important text are to be place here. 
It may or may not longer than the text we have here. You never know.
    </p>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 ul{
      list-style-type: none;
   }

   li  {
       position: relative; /* Will help curtail overlap */
      padding-left: 20px; /* Reserves a space for the square dot */
    }

    li:before {   
       content: '\f0c8';
       position: absolute;
       left: 0; /* Places the square dot at the space created by the LI padding */
       font-family: fontAwesome;
     }
```

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/kcuuqmb8/8/)

Answer (score 2):

i think you are expecting like this

### Fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/myYUh/88/**

I have added some example found on jsfiddle, i work around little bit. it might help you.

CSS

```
.icons-ul{  
    width:100px;
}

.icons-ul>li {
position: relative;
}

icons-ul {
margin-left: 2.142857142857143em;
list-style-type: none;
}

ul, ol {
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icons-ul .icon-li {
position: absolute;
left: -2.142857142857143em;
width: 2.142857142857143em;
text-align: center;
line-height: inherit;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
display: inline;
width: auto;
height: auto;
line-height: normal;
vertical-align: baseline;
background-image: none;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
margin-top: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="icons-ul">
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Bulleted lists (like this one)</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Buttons</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Button groups</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Navigation</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>Prepended form inputs</li>
  <li><i class="icon-li icon-ok"></i>&hellip;and many more with custom CSS</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late replay but check how I solved it.

```css
ul li{ display: flex; padding: 10px 0; }
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
/>

<ul>
  <li>
<i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
Font Awesome is the internet's icon library and toolkit used by millions of
designers, developers, and content creators.
  </li>
  <li>
<i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
Font Awesome is the internet's icon library and toolkit used by millions of
designers, developers, and content creators. Font Awesome is the internet's
icon library and toolkit used by millions of designers, developers, and
content creators.
  </li>
  <li>
<i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
Font Awesome is the internet's icon library and toolkit
  </li>
  <li>
<i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
Font Awesome is the internet's icon library and toolkit used by millions of
designers, developers, and content creators.
  </li>
</ul>
```